# iPhone - Replace GoogleMap MapKit user's direction blue dot with spinning arrow

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, google-maps, mapkit

How may I show an arrow that shows the users direction instead (over ?) the existing blue dot in the MapKit on a GoogleMap view ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation of the `mapView:viewForAnnotation:` delegate method:

> If the object in the annotation parameter is an instance of the MKUserLocation class, you can provide a custom view to denote the user’s location. To display the user’s location using the default system view, return nil.

So you should do just that. Check the class of the annotation for `MKUserLocation` and in case of a successful match, return a custom view. You must take care to update this view yourself whenever the user's heading changes.

Comment: do you have some liinks that could help me to "build" the arrow view ? Do I NEED to subclass MKAnnotationView ?